# How to add WCF service reference in Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, visual-studio-2005

What do I need to allow Visual Studio 2005 to add WCF service reference to a project?

I know I should just use Visual Studio 2008, but I'm preparing for a "what-if" situation where the client does not have VS2008 just yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want visual studio 2005 integration they have to have at least .net 3.0 installed. The client can then use svcutil.exe to generate the proxy.

Take a look here on how to use WCF in VS 2005 using the orcas extensions:
http://www.15seconds.com/issue/061130.htm

Alternatively:
From what I can tell MS never released a final WCF add in for VS2005, but the final CTP is still out there: http://downloads.zdnet.co.uk/0,1000000375,39328336s,00.htm

You can use that WCF add in instead of the more general and more beta orcas extension that is mentioned in the 15 seconds article. I believe the CTP will give you the "add service reference" option.

Comment: Thanks for the link, since it seems like Microsoft no longer host it. Gonna have to download it later though, because the office's internet filter found the word 'sex' in the link. :)

Comment: Funny! From what I've been able to gather MS really wants people to move to 2008, however since those CTPs are out in the wild, they can still be used.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I think your best bet is probably to provide the already-generated proxy class(es) to the client.

Answer (score -1):

The following is a post that will walk you through all the necessary to create a WCF service in Visual Studio 2005 including how to add necessary references:

http://tyblog.in/

Comment: -1: The OP is looking for a Service Reference. Not a Service with References.