# How to acess the WCF service if the is service is authenticated

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication

i am using the visual studio 2005 in that i want to get some methods from the WCF service.

i called the WCF service but i cant to able to access it because it is authenticated by the

client credentials so i am getting error as like "PERMISSION DENIED TO GET THIS METHOD". How

to pass the credentials  from visual studio 2005 to access that WCF service?.As i am new WCF

service please guide me? same code i have posted.

```
EmployeeService service = new EmployeeService();
```

Comment: Did you search for solutions? Step by step guide http://blog.adnanmasood.com/2010/04/29/step-by-step-guide-for-authenticating-wcf-service-with-username-and-password-over-ssl/

Comment: Service is already authenticated only i want to pass the username and password to that service they have used client credentials  but i am using .net 2005 there is no  options like this.

Comment: WCF isn't fully supported under 2005...  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346329/how-to-add-wcf-service-reference-in-visual-studio-2005

Comment: Is it possible for youn to temporarily disable the authentication on the service (side)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.webclientprotocol.credentials%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) property. For example,

```
EmployeeService service = new EmployeeService();
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredentials(userName, password);
```